# Regex/Replace any chars inside match combination

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, replace

For example

```
var string = 'width="300" height="650"'
```

i would like to update height in that string and get something like

```
string = string.replace(/height="..."/g, 'height="150"');
//... as any symbol
```

how to make reg expression who does not care value of height, to replace it with new one?

You can play with it here, in example:
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MTKRY/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var string = 'width="300" height="650"';
string = string.replace(new RegExp(/height=\"[0-9]+\"/g), 'height="150"');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w3Qd9/)

Comment: yes :) thx. seems working! have to improve my regex skills a bit :)

Answer (score 2):

for case insensitive use:

> .replace(new RegExp(/height=\"[0-9]+\"/**gi**), 'height="150"');